# Real buffers usage guid-lines

Tags: c#, .net, buffer

Now i started work on typical application that is massively using buffers.. i was surprised that i can't find good clear guide on this topic.

I have couple questions.

1) When do i prefer to use buffer in unmanaged heap memory over managed memory?
I know that object allocation is faster on .net then on the unmanaged heap and object destruction is much more expensive on .net because of GC overhead, so i think that it will be little faster to use unmanaged. When should i use fixed{} and when Marshal.AllocHGlobal()?

2) As i understand it is more effective to use week reference for both managed and unmanaged buffers in .net if it buffer possible can be reused after some time (based on user actions), isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to manually manage your memory allocations using native "buffers" is going to be difficult at best with .NET.  You can't allocate managed types into the unmanaged buffers, so they'll only be usable for structured data, in which case, there's little advantage over  a simple managed array (which will stay in memory contiguously, etc).

In general, it's typically a better approach to try to manage how you're allocating and letting go of objects, and try to manually reuse them as appropriate (if, and only if, memory pressure is an issue for you).

As for some of your specific points:

> I know that object allocation is faster on .net then on the unmanaged heap and object destruction is much more expensive on .net because of GC overhead, so i think that it will be little faster to use unmanaged.

I think your assumptions here are a bit flawed.  Object allocation, at the point of allocation, is typically faster in .NET, as the CLR will potentially have preallocated memory it can already use.  Object "destruction" is also faster on .NET, though there is a deferred cost due to GC that *can* be a bit higher (though it's not always).  There are a lot of factors here, mainly focused around object lifecycles - if you allow your objects to be promoted to Gen1 or especially Gen2, then things can potentially get difficult to track and measure, as GC compaction costs can be higher.

> When should i use fixed{} and when Marshal.AllocHGlobal()?

In general, you would (very) rarely use either in C#.  You're typically better off leaving your memory unpinned, and allowing the GC to do its work properly, which in turn tends to lead to better GC heuristics overall.

> 2) As i understand it is more effective to use week reference for both managed and unmanaged buffers in .net if it buffer possible can be reused after some time (based and user actions), isn't it?

Not necessarily.  Reusing objects and keeping them alive longer than necessary has some serious drawbacks, as well.  This will probably guarantee that the memory will get promoted into Gen2, which will potentially make life worse, not better.

Typically, my advice would be to trust the system, but measure as you go.  If, and only if, you find a real problem, there are almost always ways to address *those specific issues* (without resorting to unmanaged or manually managing memory buffers).  Working with raw memory should be an absolute last resort when dealing with a managed code base.

Comment: and when i need to pass buffer to native API will it be better to pass managed pinned object or the unmanaged buffer on heap? (for instance i need buffer with zeroes to fill file)

Comment: @BransDs For your example, I'd just use a managed API to fill the file.  In general, though, pinning and passing the pinned pointer will avoid unnecessary copies.